# Initialize map with custom class inside struct

Tags: c++, c++11, stdmap

I have the following `map` in a `struct`:

```
struct X {
    std::map<double, Color> colorMap
};
```

I have trouble initialize the `map` from inside the structure, especially because of the `Color` class.

I've tried the following:

```
std::map<double, Color> max_speed_color_map = {{0.5, Color()}, {1, Color()}, {1.5, Color()}, {2, Color()});
```

but I get this error:

```
error: C2797: 'colorMap': list initialization inside member initializer list or non-static data member initializer is not implemented
```

Comment: Does your compiler support C++11?

Comment: Yes it does. I'm using MSVC.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn793970.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: What version of MSVC? Also, parentheses are unbalanced

Comment: MSVC 12.0. @PiotrSkotnicki was right. See my updated post.

Comment: The answer should _never_ be edited into the question, instead write it as a separate answer.

Comment: Done. Will accept my answer in two days (can't before that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @PiotrSkotnick's answer, the solution was to declare the map inside the struct constructor:

```
X() : colorMap({{0.5, Color()}, {1, Color()}}) : {}
```